# php: how to match all script tags except with specific type

Tags: php, regex

I want to search for every script tag in a certain content except scripts with type="text/x-template".

This pattern matches all the scripts:

```
'/(\\s*)<script(\\b[^>]*?>)([\\s\\S]*?)<\\/script>(\\s*)/i'
```

But I don't know how to make it to exclude "text/x-template".

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
preg_match_all("/<script.*type=\"(?!text\/x-template).*>(.*)<\/script>/im", $input_lines, $output_array);
```

See it in action:
http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/jOB

Comment: Also note that you should prepare it for the case when the script tag has no type attribute.

Comment: white space should also be considered since `.*` won't match line breaks or spaces

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Regex to parse HTML or XML! Use DOMDocument!
See my answer to this question here:

[get from this line <topalbums artist="Adele">](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43467175/get-from-this-line-topalbums-artist-adele/43467474?noredirect=1#comment73990965_43467474)

Comment: Don't use DOMDocument to parse questions. Only a NLTK can properly differentiate between "parsing" and "matching".

Answer (score -1):

I solved it.

```
/(\s*)<script(?![ \t\r\n]+type\s*=\s*"\s*text\/x\-template\s*").*?(\b[^>]*?>)([\s\S]*?)<\/script>(\s*)/
```

https://jsfiddle.net/porizm/6wrebz23/8/

Comment: Look at this question as to why you shouldn't use regex to solve this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags